# Setting custom colors and shading when printing a melted dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a melted dataframe that generates the plot below. The data is downloaded from the Federal Reserve, and the first few lines of the melted dataframe are as follows:

```
> head(df_melt)
      Date                            Variable value
1 Jun 1967 Chauvet-Piger Recession Probability 0.183
2 Jul 1967 Chauvet-Piger Recession Probability 0.108
3 Aug 1967 Chauvet-Piger Recession Probability 0.039
4 Sep 1967 Chauvet-Piger Recession Probability 0.096
5 Oct 1967 Chauvet-Piger Recession Probability 0.048
6 Nov 1967 Chauvet-Piger Recession Probability 0.036
```

I plot it using the following code:

```
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = Date, y= value)) +
        geom_line(aes(color = Variable)) +
        labs(x = "Date", y = "Unemployment Rate") +
#Some more stuff related to axes, legend etc.
```

I would like to

1. Choose the colors
2. Shade the area under the UREC recession indicator with a light gray
   I tried setting colors by changing `aes(color = Variable)` to `color = line_colors`

where `line_colors` is a vector of colors I have defined, but get an error message:

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1992): colour
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have also tried `scale_color_manual` without success. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix these two problems?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

[image: Recession probabilities]

Comment: `geom_line()` doesn't have a fill. You might want to try `geom_area()` instead. To choose the colours yourself, use `scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))` in combination with `aes(color = Variable, ...)`.

Comment: scale_color_manual works perfectly. Thank you very much. But geom_area applies to all the series - I just want to apply it to UNREC? How can I make only one of the series in the melted dataframe into an area chart?